# Greatest integer function inequality solution

Tags: inequality

If $\lfloor x+\lfloor x\rfloor\rfloor \le 2$ then what are all the possible values of $x$? Please tell how to proceed and tell the solution by graph method of possible. Explain how to sketch the graph of left hand side.

Comment: What do you mean with the brackets [ ] ?

Comment: @Nogard,it is floor function

Comment: Yes it's floor function

Comment: $\lfloor x\rfloor$ is the more standard notation for the [floor function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floor_and_ceiling_functions) of $x$ than $[x]$. The latter could more normally denote the [nearest integer function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest_integer_function) of $x$.

Answer (score 1):

$\lfloor x + \lfloor x\rfloor\rfloor\leq 2$ holds clearly for $x<2$. Also note that $\lfloor x + \lfloor x\rfloor\rfloor = 2\lfloor x\rfloor$.

The graph is similar like the one in http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FloorFunction.html. You have to consider additionally the constraint.

Comment: Sorry but your explanation was not very clear it indeed confused me more

Comment: @Ujjwal Which part is confusing?